# Regular Expression Minimum Length

Tags: regex

This will eventually be part of a larger expression but I've reduced it down to a much simpler form here (ie, there will be a true possibility of 40 characters instead of the 19 possible here).  Given the following input:

```
;123?T
```

I get a successful match against this regex:

```
^(?:;(\d{0,19})\?.){1,40}$
```

However, I do not get a match against this regex:

```
^(?:;(\d{0,19})\?.){3,40}$
```

The only thing I'm changing is the minimum length, both of which the input should satisfy.  Why does the first one find a match and the second one doesn't?  Maybe I'm just not understanding this quantifier but I thought it was simply {MIN, MAX}.

Also, I have tested this in both of the following online testers:

[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)

[regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: You're not changing the minimum length, but the number of repeats of the pattern `(?:;(\d{0,19})\?.)` (which includes `;`, `?` and an additional character).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the first part of the expression `^(?:;(\d{0,19})\?.)` you are matching all of this `;123?T`.

With the next part of the expression `{1,40}` you are saying match the above 1 through 40 times.  Notice that if you try to match  `;123?T` 3 times in a row, this obviously will not work, and that is the case when you say `{3,40}`.

Comment: the second regular expression will match something like: ;123?T;456?T;789?T   if that makes the answer more clear. the second regex is asking to match your whole group three times at a minimum.